# ArrayList - how can I check if an index exists?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm using `ArrayList<String>` and I add data at specific indices, how can I check if a specific index exists?

Should I simply `get()` and check the value? Or should I wait for an exception?
Is there another way?

**Update:** Thank you for your answers, but because I'm only adding stuff at specific indices, the length of the list will not show me which are available.

Comment: Have a look at a Set perhaps its more suited to what you need?

Comment: Then you're gonna have to `get()` and check for `null` - don't rely on exceptions though. Consider using a `HashTable` instead http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

Answer (score 209, accepted):

The method `arrayList.size()` [returns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#size()) the number of items in the list - so if the index is greater than or equal to the `size()`, it doesn't exist.

```
if(index >= myList.size() || index < 0){
  //index does not exists
}else{
 // index exists
}
```

Comment: That should be "greater or equal to the `size()`" since it is a zero-based index.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that to make this atomic you should probably perform the size() check and corresponding conditional index based look-up whilst locking the list.

Comment: please note that i mark this answer at the correct is because the owner (Amarghosh) as answered my question in a comment to my question. HashTable will suite my needs much better.

Comment: what if you are setting items in the arraylist with ID of the item?

ex.
mylist.set(1, item1);
mylist.set(3, item3); //skipping 2

I guess HashMap is more suitable for that scenario?

Comment: this doesn't quite satisfy me .. if I want to do something in the list if the index is already there, but otherwise to prep it.. with a new list I'm going to start at `index = 0` and my `list.size() == 0` too. so the first time I check it will be true & I'll prep the list to do stuff. but the next time at that index, my index will still be `index = 0` and now I am re-initializing that element in the list when I was supposed to be doing stuff. The 1st thought is to `&&` a second condition like `list.get(index) == null` but that not working is why there are questions like this one

Comment: Added Code snippet to the answer, so people understand it easily

Answer (score 88):

While you got a dozen suggestions about using the size of your list, which work for lists with linear entries, no one seemed to read your question.

If you add entries manually at different indexes none of these suggestions will work, as you need to check for a specific index.

Using *if ( list.get(index) == null )* will not work either, as get() throws an exception instead of returning null.

Try this:

```
try {
    list.get( index );
} catch ( IndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
    list.add( index, new Object() );
}
```

Here a new entry is added if the index does not exist. You can alter it to do something different.

Comment: Thank you, needed this technique for unit testing whether array indexes exist.

Comment: Remember to avoid using `try/catch` for this kind of work, it will slow down your program by 50% or maybe more.. error checking adds like a strap to your existing code to slow it down.. better to avoid it in critical areas. Checking for `length` in this case is the best thing you can do, since the `index` will always be less then the `length`,old `index`'s will get shifted and become new `index`'s if you `remove` them so that's why the rule checking for `length` always will work.

Comment: @SSpoke ... While I agree, try/catch is far from 'a good' answer; it will address the problem when the list is sparse.  I prefer the suggestion to use an array: Object[] ary; below or a hash.

Comment: Using exceptions to for flow control, as this example shows, it is an anti-pattern https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Comment: Accessing an out of bound element can be prevented with length check.
Try to avoid exception handlers for situations which can be guarded.
Exceptions are for exceptional behaviour, something which you couldn't have foreseen. Sir Martin Fowler goes in length for this one https://martinfowler.com/articles/replaceThrowWithNotification.html

Answer (score 14):

This is what you need ...

```
public boolean indexExists(final List list, final int index) {
    return index >= 0 && index < list.size();
}
```

Why not use an plain old array? Indexed access to a List is a code smell I think.

Comment: Not always, since he might want the ArrayList to grow over time, and that a array can't do.

Answer (score 14):

This is for [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) developers ending up here:

```kotlin
if (index in myList.indices) {
  // index is valid
}
```

Other solutions:

```kotlin
// The rangeUntil operator (..<) is still exprimental in Kotlin 1.7.20
if (index in 0..<myList.size) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
if (index in 0 until myList.size) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
if (index in 0..myList.lastIndex) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
if (index >= 0 && index <= myList.lastIndex) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
// Note: elements of the list should be non-null
if (myList.getOrNull(index) != null) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
// Note: elements of the list should be non-null
myList.getOrNull(index)?.let { element ->
  // index is valid; use the element
}
```

Comment: This is why I love Kotlin :D

Comment: Awesome solution! Kotlin ❤️

Answer (score 12):

Usually I just check if the index is less than the array size

```
if (index < list.size()) {
    ...
}
```

If you are also concerned of index being a negative value, use following

```
if (index >= 0 && index < list.size()) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: How does this provide any value over the [accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2131825/642706) of several years ago?

Comment: I guess in your view it does not provide any value, but I saw a comment of roberto tomás on the accepted answer, assuming he did not quite understood the accepted answer. check it out
"with a new list I'm going to start at index = 0 and my list.size() == 0 too. so the first time I check it will be true"
I decided to post a separate answer to help any future confusion.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your update (which probably should be another question).
You should use an array of these objects instead an ArrayList,
so you can simply check the value for null:

```
Object[] array = new Object[MAX_ENTRIES];
..
if ( array[ 8 ] == null ) {
   // not available
}
else {
   // do something
}
```

Best-Practice

If you don't have hundred of entries in your array you should consider organizing it as a class to get rid of the magic numbers 3,8 etc.

Control flow using exception is bad practice.

Comment: If array[8] does not exist, you will encounter ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 6):

Since Java 9 there is a standard way of checking if an index belongs to the array - [Objects#checkIndex()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#checkIndex-int-int-) :

```
List<Integer> ints = List.of(1,2,3);
System.out.println(Objects.checkIndex(1,ints.size())); // 1
System.out.println(Objects.checkIndex(10,ints.size())); //IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: `of()` method also is added in **Java 9** 
 to the class **List**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of--

Answer (score 3):

You can check the size of an `ArrayList` using the `size()` method. This will return the maximum index +1

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the size of the array.

```
package sojava;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static Object get(ArrayList list, int index) {
        if (list.size() > index) { return list.get(index); }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(""); list.add(""); list.add("");        
        System.out.println(get(list, 4));
        // prints 'null'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty test for whether an index exists or not. in your implementation replace list With your list you are testing.

```
public boolean hasIndex(int index){
    if(index < list.size())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

or for 2Dimensional ArrayLists...

```
public boolean hasRow(int row){
    if(row < _matrix.size())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: List don't have `.length` it has `list.size()` but it's no big deal I screw up like this all the time haha I rely on compiler to guide me on that one. You were probably thinking of primitive arrays

Comment: Thanks for catching that. The containers cardinality can be easy to forget.

Answer (score 1):

a simple way to do this:

```
try {
  list.get( index ); 
} 
catch ( IndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
  if(list.isEmpty() || index >= list.size()){
    // Adding new item to list.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your index is less than the size of your list then it does exist, possibly with `null` value. If index is bigger then you may call `ensureCapacity()`  to be able to use that index.

If you want to check if a value at your index is `null` or not, call `get()`

Comment: Calling ensureCapacity(int) won't increase the size of the List, only the capacity; i.e. "potential size" so out of bounds index look-ups would still fail.

Comment: Also, why call ensureCapacity(int) at all?  It could be an incredibly expensive operation if for example the list's current size is 5 and you want to determine the value of item#: 100,000,000.

Comment: I meant that indices less than size() always exist, those which are >= size() don't and one can't use them (== call set()) until list becomes big enough.

Calling ensureCapacity is not enough indeed, one needs to change the size by adding elements.

Comment: Wrong explanation about what ensureCapacity(int) actually does. It does nothing with ArrayList size.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the index to check");
    int i  = input.nextInt();
    if (i > tasksList.size() || i < 0 ){
        System.out.println("invalid input");
    }else {
            //your code
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).