# How to detect if an index exists in an array (String[])?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using the `str.split("!")` to pull a string in half when there is an exclamation mark contained in the string.  With the way the code is set up I will get a 1 index array if there is no exclamation mark and a 2 index array if there is one.

Code:

```
String file, macroName;

String[] fileAndMacro = string.split("!");
if(fileAndMacro[0] != null)
    file = new File(fileAndMacro[0]);
if(fileAndMacro[1] != null)
    macroName = fileAndMacro[1];
```

If I put in a string with an exclamation mark, it works.  For example `"test!string"` would return `fileAndMacro[0] = "test"` and `fileAndMacro[1] = "string"`.

The problem is when I don't have an exclamation mark (as some of you can probably tell from my code).  I simply get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  So, clearly a null check is not doing the trick.  Which makes sense considering there can't be a null value in memory if no space has been allocated for the value to be stored in.

Despite my understanding of this, I'm not sure how to check to see if that second index exists or not.  How do I check to see if an index exists or not in real time?

Comment: You don't need to check array elements for null: they will never be null.

Comment: Really, so something like `array[0] = null` would throw an error or something?

Comment: No, something like this can _never_ happen with `String.split()` ;) If the array is empty, trying and accessing it will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Arrays in Java are allocated at init time and not resizable, and a zero-length array is possible

Comment: Ah, okay, I get your point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayList - how can I check if an index exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131802/arraylist-how-can-i-check-if-an-index-exists)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to check length of your array, so:

```
if(fileAndMacro.length > 1)
   macroName = fileAndMacro[1];
```

By accessing an index that doesn't exist, you would be accessing some other space in memory which does not belong to your created array (actually created in the `split()` method), that's why you get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just test `fileAndMacro.length`. If it is 2 or larger, there was at least one exclamation mark.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not quite true if you use `.split()` without an integer argument... Splitting `"!"` will give a zero length array too. You need to pass a _negative_ argument to `.split()` so that it really splits by the book.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of an array using its length property  `array.length`

```
if (array.length  < 2){
    //perform some operation you want

}
```

Answer (score -1):

This question can apply to Kotlin as well. So, here is the solution for Kotlin:

```kotlin
if (index in myArray.indices) {
  // index is valid
}
```

Other solutions:

```kotlin
myArray.getOrNull(index)?.let { element ->
  // index is valid; use the element
}
```

```kotlin
if (myList.getOrNull(index) != null) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
if (index in 0..myArray.lastIndex) {
  // index is valid
}
```

```kotlin
if (index >= 0 && index <= myArray.lastIndex) {
  // index is valid
}
```

There is [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2131802/8583692) for collections.